# Search for file type in a pull request using GitHub API

Tags: php, sql, github

I'm building a changelog for my company's repository on GitHub, using GitHub's API. We merge once a week, and frequently with pull requests there are database changes that we include as .sql files. I'm looking for a way to find any .sql files that are being added in the pull request.

The best I've come up with so far, is to just call the API using curl and get all of the files in a given pull request number. Then use PHP to find the ones that have a .sql extension to the file name. Is there a better way to do this using the GitHub API?

> `https://api.github.com/repos/{$repoOwner}/{$repoName}/pulls/{$prNum}/files`

This, however, results in all of the files from the pull request, but I only want the .sql files. I've tried various combinations of `search/pulls` or `pulls/search/code` with no luck so far.

Including any parameters has not resulted in any reduction of the responding results. I've tried `file-filters%5B%5D=.sql&show-viewed-files=true` - which is what is generated when searching a pull request for .sql files on their website results in, as well as a smattering of combinations of that using the `q=` format I've seen in various places. I've had no luck, I think I must be missing something, because it seems like this should be possible given the current API abilities.